# Askbot - No module named xdg.Config

Tags: python, django, centos, askbot

I have installed Python 2.7.3 + Django 1.3.1 + Askbot and [these requirements](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot_requirements.txt)

When I run my server on port 8000, and I try to establishing a connection with a browser I have this unusual error: ***Could not import myapp01.deps.django_authopenid.views. Error was: No module named xdg.Config*** .

Traceback output is: http://pastebin.com/4uzbWvR0

My operating system is CentOS 6.3 and all the installations is automated and managed by Puppet.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to install the [`xdg`](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg) module:

```
pip install pyxdg
```

Comment: @Flat You might want to check that you have all the dependencies for askbot, it's strange that you're missing this specific one.

Comment: It's strange because don't compare on the askbot_requirements.txt from the askbot github. Thanks again

Comment: @Flat It could be a dependency of a dependency though. Installing `askbot` in a fresh virtualenv doesn't seem to install `xdg` though. Maybe some dependency is using it but didn't list it in their `requirements.txt` file. Using `grep -R "xdg.Config" *` didn't yield anything else, so my guess is that it's required in another of your dependencies, maybe `myapp01.deps.django_authopenid'` from looking at your pastebin.